# Need to create a Theme demo site that features multiple themes

Tags: plugins, functions, themes, widgets

I would like to create a site like: http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=sentient for my clients, so that they can see the range of themes I offer. I own many templates from different providers, and sending them to the providers will not help as there are quite a few and not all offer this functionality (not to mention that the UI can be confusing to my clients)

I want the site to be super simple to use, and provide the ability at first to just switch themes on using a demo site (Wordpress site with content)

Found this previous [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31183/theme-demo-in-live-site) about same subject, this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-switcher-reloaded/) was offered there, but the solution is far from simple in that the all templates need to support some specific functionality (the theme switching widget) - this is not good enough.

I'd appreciate any suggestions you may have (creating a site with an upper frame that switches sites below?) - problem is I have very little time to experiment on this, and am looking for someone with the knowledge who is willing to share.

Comment: "*This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*"

Comment: I thought it was pretty straight forward, I give concrete examples and existing solutions that point in the direction (I think). How can Improve on this? I am a newbie at asking....

Comment: @ChipBennett I'd appreciate any tips you can give me on re-writing this question... See my comment above as well. Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's not so much that the question isn't *straight-forward* enough, but rather that it represents a very localized set of requirements for an overly broad scenario. I'm not sure of the best way to "improve" it, but others might have some suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about a plugin like: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-switcher/

Comment: This is a valid and working solution, it just doesn't fit my needs, but since no better reply was given, I'm accepting the answer

Comment: if a theme switching plugin doesn't provide enough functionality then you might have to create a multisite network where each new theme is a new "site".  this seems like a lot of maintenance though. theme switcher does provide a template tag ( wp_theme_switcher('dropdown') ) that might help if a widget isn't appropriate....

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info, i'll see about how I can create a file or something that can get auto included in any new theme, (be a feature of the system on a MU site? is there such a thing)?      And this file/mod will include a floating div that will always be located at the same point (movable by the user) which can contain the template_tag, and the plugin will be added to that site...    Then all I'll have to do is drop the theme in and enable it for the demo site...      need to think a little more about this.

Comment: i was thinking you could put that template tag in your theme, but well if the theme is switched i doubt it would still work.  what if you create another plugin, add the template to the wp_footer() hook and absolutely position )(enqueue a stylesheet maybe) it to be at the top.  that's very much like how the admin bar works now.  that should persist between theme changes.

Comment: Did it, done...
a little plugin does all the work, now all themes "Support" switching, and it works beautifully in 10 lines of code altogether including protective coding, supports both Theme Switcher and Theme Switcher Reloaded
I'll try to upload the plugin to [Wordpress.org](http://www.wordpress.org), this will be my first plugin ever...

Comment: check it out at http://www.eshel.us/wordpress/plugins/Floating_Theme_List/

I started the process of uploading it into Wordpress.org, apparently this takes time to at least upload your first plugin, since they want to review?

Comment: awesome. yes all themes and plugins get reviewed before being released.  helps keep quality up and nasty stuff out.  the best thing you can to help move the queue along is over to review other plugins.

Comment: Plugin was accepted and is now official (in the directory) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/floating-theme-list/ please check it out and review. Also you want to help a little please please answer or comment here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47755/ettiqute-question-when-i-want-to-extend-a-plugin  thank you

Comment: guess it didn't take all that long to review.  cool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, theme switcher is good.

You still need to install all of the different themes you want to demo, and modify them to suit your needs...