# A question of etiquette when forking a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am updating (forking) a WP plugin over on Github - with some functionality on the plugins roadmap - so I know this feature is desired by the developer and will probably be included in their next update through WP plugins.

When updating the plugin with my additions, do I also update the readme.txt file etc and add my username as a contributor (I guess this should be the case)? Or should I contact them and ask to be put on?

It is my expectation that if I had contributed then I would be credited here but not sure on the right approach!

Thanks for any advice ;)

Comment: IMO, when you update the `readme.txt` you also make a kind of contribution. So, if plugin authors do not wants to use your version you'll not be credited. Otherwise they should keep your `readme` too (if it is not heavy modified and satisfies their requirements).

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I'm not sure it's a good fit for the WPSE Q&A format, which encourages fact-based answers and discourages opinion-based answers. Also, this isn't really a WordPress-specific question; it's more a licensing/copyright/attribution question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far, @ChipBennett, your probably right about the format of the Q&A and being fact based however I do think its specific to WordPress, as this is to do with accreditation in a specific WordPress file and to do with how this works with the WordPress SVN

Please also see this similar (but different question - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47755/what-is-the-etiquette-on-extending-a-plug-in)

Comment: If you are maintaining your own fork it's best to make it clear that it is just that - _your_ fork of original project. If your fork is only for contributing changes upstream I think it's up to policy of original developer how to handle attribution, I wouldn't try to impose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO Yes put your name as a contributor, you've contributed to that fork. However personally I'd let the lead developer know just so you and they don't duplicate work (unless they decide they don't want your code, but you won't know that till you've tried).

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that, if I'm forking it and modifying code, while it is sitting on my account there is absolutely no reason not to add myself as a contributor... if the fork is then pulled it is up to the lead developer to integrate that change.  Thanks